# Can the school force me to log into my social media accounts?

Tags: united-kingdom, privacy, human-rights, school, school-law

I live in the UK and go to a public school. Sometimes the school will force students to log into the social media account because there might be some cyberbullying. Is this legal if they have a reason? And is it legal if they do not have a reason? If I refuse to log into my account they will exclude me from the school for ever

Comment: There's certainly no Intrinsic right for children to have privacy in their social activity, as against the adults who exist to supervise their behaviour. It's the same as adults have little right against state authorities who have quite free access to social media data.

Comment: @MemeRuler: what exactly do you mean by "forcing to log into your account". Do they want "access" to your account or do they want you to use social media and you don't want to ?

Comment: In order to confuse people, a "public school" in the UK means an independent school, like Eton or Harrow, where exclusion is largely a matter of the contract between the school and the pupil's parents/guardians. This is different from any of the several kinds of school run or funded by government, where there are regulations about discipline and appeals. The reach of the Human Rights Act into private schools is very limited. Can you clarify whether you really mean a public (i.e. private) school?

Comment: If you were cyber bullying there would be evidence obtainable via the complaintent's account.  I don't see why they would need to log into your account.

Comment: @alexg I go to a state school

Comment: @Hilmar, Sorry if i caused any confusion. I mean they want to access my account

Comment: @MichaelHall For example if I am on a discord server, And if someone in that server was cyberbullied. They might ask to access my account to see if they can find further evidence on the offence